# article reviewing or article reviews

Tags: grammar, american-english

I just want to know which one of the following sentences is grammatically correct and meaningful:

1. They have invited me **to do article reviews** for their newspaper
2. They have invited me **to do article reviewing** for their newspaper

The context here is, I have been invited to work as a peer reviewer to write comments about the articles submitted on the newspaper website...

Comment: Use of the word "do" slightly weakens the statement. It is best to say directly, "They have invited me to review articles for their newspaper."

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct. *do* is a transitive verb, and the receiving noun in the first sentence is "article reviews" while the receiving noun in the second sentence is "article reviewing".

The first sounds more natural, and it implies some fix quantity. For example, you can do 5 reviews, 10 reviews, 100 reviews, etc.

The second feels like it's more of a general job versus a quantifiable metric as in the previous sentence.

Comment: Hello, Neel. While this is true, it has been covered before on ELU, and we try to avoid duplication / bloat. While I don't usually use the ill-defined (variously defined) word 'gerund', an in-house search for 'noun' + 'gerund' will turn up duplicates.